# Using Nexus 3 how can I upload a multi-line script?

Tags: nexus

The manual gives this example

`{
  "name": "maven",
  "type": "groovy",
  "content": "repository.createMavenHosted('private')"
}`

But if the content is multiple lines of code then this fails.  How do I reformat something more complex for uploading?

Comment: Did you try - https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/scripting/complex-script?

Answer (score 0):

The comment on your post is spot on, you can use:

https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/blob/nexus-3.x/scripting/complex-script/addUpdateScript.groovy

Ala: `groovy addUpdateScript.groovy -u admin -p admin123 -f scriptFile.groovy [-n explicitName] [-h nx3Url]`

Should make things a bit easier for you.

For posterity sake adding another line using the simple example you have:

```js
{
  "name": "mavenandnpm",
  "type": "groovy",
  "content": "repository.createMavenHosted('private'); repository.createNpmProxy('npmjs-org','https://registry.npmjs.org');"
}
```